# What kind of code element is the 'apply from' part in the gradle DSL closure passed to 'buildscript'?

Tags: gradle, groovy, dsl, gradle-plugin, build-script

I'm trying to figure out what kind of code element the `apply from` is:

```
buildscript {
    apply from: rootProject.file("gradle/versions.gradle")
    repositories {
        google()
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath plugin.android_gradle_plugin
        ...
    }
}
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27335721/5233188) i understand that the `buildscript`  gradle function is called with a closure, so we can add the omitted brackets:

```
buildscript ({
    apply from: rootProject.file("gradle/versions.gradle")
    repositories ({
        google()
        ...
    })
    dependencies ({
        classpath plugin.android_gradle_plugin
        ...
    })
})
```

I first thougt the `apply from` is a [label](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_labeled_statements) but then when could that label actually be used? Not to mention that groovy doesn't mention that labels are allowed to have spaces.

Then i thought it could be a property initialization (`new Coordinates(latitude: 43.23, longitude: 3.67)`), but `apply from` is in a closure.

At last i read about "curry", like this:

```
def nCopies = { int n, String str -> str*n }    
def twice = nCopies.curry(2)                    
assert twice('bla') == 'blabla'
```

So the `apply from` part could be evaluated first when using the closure, but even then i am still unaware if the `apply from` is a label or some kind of assignment and what purpose it serves.

### So, what kind of code element is the `apply from` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: It's a function call with a map as argument

```
apply from: rootProject.file("gradle/versions.gradle")
```

Is short for:

```
apply(from: rootProject.file("gradle/versions.gradle"))
```

("Parens are optional, if unambiguous")

Is short for:

```
apply([from: rootProject.file("gradle/versions.gradle"]))
```

(If maps are passed, you can leave out the `[]` around the map literal)